# Shopware 6 / Adding Local fonts to Subshop

Tags: fonts, less, local, shopware6, lesscss-resources

can anyone help please?

I need to help to set local fonts to Subshop.

Local fonts working good on main shop, but not on subshop.

I did these steps to implement local fonts to Subshop. (Same steps was used for main Shop)

1. Fonts location:\shopware\custom\plugins\UniTheme\src\Resources\public\assets\fonts\
2. in file - **override.scss** : **$my-asset-path: '#{$sw-asset-theme-url}/bundles/unitheme/assets' !default;**
3. in file - **base.scss** add these font-face (these fonts are added to fonts location - step 1)

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'DIN-Regular';
src: url('#{$my-asset-path}/fonts/DIN-Regular.otf');
src: local('DIN-Regular'), local('DIN-Regular'),
url('#{$my-asset-path}/fonts/DIN-Regular.otf') format('opentype');
font-weight: 100;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'Hind-Regular';
src: url('#{$my-asset-path}/fonts/Hind-Regular.eot');
src: local('Roboto Medium'), local('Roboto-Medium'),
url('#{$my-asset-path}/fonts/Hind-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('#{$my-asset-path}/fonts/Hind-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
url('#{$my-asset-path}/fonts/Hind-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
url('#{$my-asset-path}/fonts/Hind-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: 500;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'FrankRuhlLibre-Regular';
src: url('#{$my-asset-path}/fonts/FrankRuhlLibre-Regular.ttf');
src: local('FrankRuhlLibre-Regular'), local('DIN-Regular'),
url('#{$my-asset-path}/fonts/FrankRuhlLibre-Regular.ttf') format('opentype');
font-weight: 100;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: SkemaProOmni;
src: url('#{$my-asset-path}/fonts/SkemaProOmni-Medium.ttf') format("truetype");
}
```

4. **./console assets:install**
5. **./console theme:compile**

Did i forget something?

Thank you very much for your help.
Best Regards Petr.

I tried already same steps, like by other shops / but this is first subshop

Comment: Is your sub shop a whole extra instance, or just another sales channel?

Comment: Hi @Ezycod  - it is just another Sales channel. What can i do then?

Comment: Can you take a look at the full URLs of the fonts in the network log, for both instances?

Comment: I tried to search that in Google Chrome in network setting, but i did not see that.
Here is live installation - so maybe - you can take a look and then tell me, where i can find that? [link](https://cilia.eu/)

Thank you very much
Best Regards Petr.

Comment: The URL is https://cilia.eu/bundles/leroi24theme/assets/fonts/Hind-Regular.woff2
And what is the URL of the Subshop? a new Domain?

Comment: https://uni-dev.4m-marketing.com/ this is that URL - but it has HTACCESS now.

I tried same way like you and it is accessible through this link

https://uni-dev.4m-marketing.com/bundles/unitheme/assets/fonts/Hind-Regular.woff2

But what that means? This is working like you sent above.

Thanks. Best Regards Petr.